# cmath.h and compile errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors, cmath

I used to work with math.h without any problem. Now, I use an external library which itself has a file called `math.h`, but which includes `< cmath>`.

Adding this library to my project (or even just adding the include directory, without touching the code) now generates tons of errors from `< cmath>` :

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\cmath(18) : error C2039: 'acosf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\cmath(18) : error C2873: 'acosf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\cmath(18) : error C2039: 'asinf' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\cmath(18) : error C2873: 'asinf' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration

[etc, etc...]

I don't understand why this happens. I am using Visual Studio 2005 and looking on the internet, it seems that this problem is solved under VS 2008. However, I'd like to stay on VS 2005...

Including `using namespace std;` everywhere, or changing the order of my includes doesn't seem to change anything. Defining `_STD_BEGIN` solves the error, but produce as many in `< xlocinfo>`.

How can this be solved?

Comment: cmath is supposed to be used from C++ code. Are you including this header from a C file?

Comment: indeed one of my files in my project is in C and included with extern "C". It includes "math.h" which is then found in the include directory of my external library, and implicitely includes cmath - I thus don't know how to fix that.
However, these compile errors seems to happen even earlier in my code, before compiling this C code.

Comment: changing this particular piece of C code to C++ doesn't seem to change all the compile errors from cmath though...

Comment: I'm not sure I read your post correctly but it seems odd that a library would ship it's own math.h file. Perhaps you are suppose to put the parent directory in your include path so that that you can `#include <my_lib/math.h>` and avoid conflicts with your compiler `math.h`?

Comment: Alexandre: of course! I didn't realize that all their header files had a relative path in the form "my_lib/myheader.h" in it ! Thanks a lot, this makes much sense!

Comment: I don't know well how stackoverflow usually works, but you can copy paste this comment as a formal answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: in my case I got this error because VC interpreted my .c file as C, which makes sense, I should have added it with a .cpp extension since I'm using STL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I read your question correctly but it seems odd that a library would ship it's own math.h file.

Perhaps you are suppose to put the parent directory in your include path so that `<my_lib/math.h>` can be included without conflicting with your compiler `<math.h>`?

Answer (score 16):

Same Problem exists in VC 10. I think, that `<cmath>` includes itself a `math.h` but insted of the correct one, which is shipped with VC it uses the one which is created in the User-Project (with different content of course).

Solution: Do never use a File named `math.h` in your Project... (Or correct the std somewhere).

Comment: After 2 hours of tearing my hair out, your comment made me spot I have a Math.h in my project, which even with different capitalisation conflicts with std's math.h . Renaming to my Math.h to MathExtensions.h   solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Now "Math" goes on my short "source files should never be named this" list.  (I have a longer list of "source files should never have names that include this string" which contains "Error", "Warning", and "Failed".)

Comment: The problem is present on VS 2015 and VS 2017 RC. Renaming Math.h into ProjectnameMath.h resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably mixing C libraries with C++ conventions.  For instance:

```
#include <math.h>
namespace TEST {
}
```

This compiles fine, whereas:

```
namespace TEST {
  #include <math.h>
}
```

This generates a large number of spurious errors.

Just to confuse the issue:

```
#include <math.h>
namespace TEST {
  #include <math.h>
}
```

This also compiles as it can only be included once (the first time).

Hence also:

```
#include <math.h>
namespace TEST {
  #include "SomethingThatIncludesMath.h"
}
```

Will work, whereas:

```
namespace TEST {
  #include "SomethingThatIncludesMath.h"
}
```

Won't.

You can also get similar problems by including C++ headers into a *.c file, rather than a *.cpp file.

I am sure that other similar mixing of C and C++ can lead to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

(1) According to Microsoft, the C2873 means;

'symbol' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
A using directive is missing a namespace keyword. This causes the compiler to misinterpret the code as a using declaration rather than a using directive.

(2) Also when I had C2873 with C2039 (I tried to merge CEF3 and Cinder), somehow I bypassed the both error by changing Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation;

Enable Minimal Rebuild: Yes(/Gm), Enable C++ Exception: Yes(/EHsc), Enable Function-Level Linking: empty